# Converting a big stored procedure into a view

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I have a stored procedure of around 500 lines developed by an ex-employee.

Is there anyway I can convert it into a View.  Going through it is hard; it's complex and I don't know much sql.

Is there anyway I can see graphical view of stored procedure as what its getting from where?

Because of security reasons, I can't post the SP.

Comment: The answer is yes, but it might be a lot harder than necessary.It depends on what the stored procedure is doing.

Comment: Also, casual English doesn't require "sir" to be polite.  Simply stating what you need or want is ok in most circumstances.

Comment: in easy words, it's like a select statement with some parameters