# What does this code line is doing

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

In reference to my question,

[Converting a big stored procedure into a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693599/converting-a-big-stored-procedure-into-a-view)

In SP i have this code line,

```
@countCrates = COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(countCratesAddress, 'EMPTY')) , @FirstCrateAddres = MIN(countCratesAddress)
```

Not sure what it's doing or how to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the SP, this variable is assigned to some values or select "countCratesAddress".
Then its used.

The Breakdown is:

```
> @FirstCrateAddres = MIN(countCratesAddress).
```

** get minimum of countCratesAddress and assign to the variable '@FirstCrateAddres'

```
> COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(countCratesAddress, 'EMPTY')).
```

** if "countCratesAddress" is null, replace it with the word "EMPTY" then take the COUNT of 
   what comes back from the DISTINCT of "countCratesAddress"